# Sharepoint and Excel VBA integration failure

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, excel-2013

I have encountered a problem when trying to retrieve file properties from SharePoint through VBA in Excel. (I can't post the workbook, but the below code should suffice).

The code in question:

```
Private Sub CheckCheckOutStatus()

    Debug.Print Application.Workbooks.CanCheckOut("http://sp.mySharepointDomain.co.uk/myFolderPath/myFile.xlsb")

End Sub
```

The issue is that on my clients PC this statement always returns false regardless of whether the file is checked out or not (They are able to check out the file manually, so it isn't a file permissions issue).

Upon further investigation, it seems to be that my specific computer is able to get the correct value from this code and none other can. It's also worth mentioning that my client and all the PC's/Users I have tested this with are all on the same shared network and so we should all have the same packages installed.

Through process of elimination we have deduced that it is related to my specific computer (and it doesn't matter who logs into it, its the PC itself) that is able to use this method correctly.

My question is to all the experts out there:

***Are there any client side or local packages/installations/permissions that could enable or disable programmatic access to the properties in SharePoint?***

Thank you for taking the time to read this, and thanks in advance to any suggestions you might have!

Answer (score 1):

I can't test this because I don't have SharePoint installed, but this looks about right...

```
Sub test()
Dim docCheckOut As String
docCheckOut = "Filepath&name"
Call UseCheckOut(docCheckOut)
End Sub

Sub UseCheckOut(docCheckOut As String)

    ' Determine if workbook can be checked out.
    If Workbooks.CanCheckOut(docCheckOut) = True Then
        Workbooks.CheckOut docCheckOut
    Else
        MsgBox "Unable to check out this document at this time."
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, unfortunately the issue I am having is that Workbooks.CanCheckOut(docCheckOut) will always equal False. I assume this is because VBA can't access the properties and so the command returns null, which defaults to False.